# How to invert colors of a picture on Mac?

Tags: image-editing

How do I invert the colors of an image?

I'm using macOS 10.13 and I wish to use built-in Apple software or freeware.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

1. Open the image in Preview.app (macOS built in default image viewer).
2. Choose Tools → Adjust Colour ⌥⌘C.
3. Swap the left-most and right-most points on the graph.

   [image]

Comment: oh my god thank you, this is absolutely amazing.

Comment: Didn't work for me and my image. Used photopea.com to invert the colors properly